# Pregunta formulario React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo un formulario en react el cual tiene el problema que al agregar el proximo elemento la lista se actualiza a los valores del ultimo elemento que se agregue a esta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] }

```js
//import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
//import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";

class Todo extends React.Component {
  state = {
   data_object: {
    item: "",
    select: ""
  },
  times: []
};

  getNames = e => {
    let data_object = this.state.data_object;
    data_object[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
  };

  getSelect = e => {
    let data_object = this.state.data_object;
    data_object[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
  };

  addItem = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let obj = this.state.data_object;
    this.setState({
      times: this.state.times.concat(obj)
    });
  };

  edit = (e, index) => {
    console.log("edit", index);
    let edit_element = this.state.times[index];
    console.log(edit_element);
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.times);
    let get_times = this.state.times.map((value, index) => {
      return (
        <li key={index} style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}>
          {value.item} - {value.select}
          <button
            style={{
              background: "#50d890",
              padding: "3px",
              color: "#FFF",
              borderRadius: "5px",
              marginLeft: "5px",
              paddingLeft: "5px",
              paddingRight: "5px",
              border: "black"
            }}
          >
            Editar
          </button>
          <button
            style={{
              background: "#f0134d",
              padding: "3px",
              color: "#FFF",
              borderRadius: "5px",
              marginLeft: "5px",
              paddingLeft: "5px",
              paddingRight: "5px",
              border: "black"
            }}
          >
            X
          </button>
        </li>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <input name="item" onChange={e => this.getNames(e)} />
          <select name="select" onChange={e => this.getSelect(e)}>
            <option>No Requerido</option>
            <option>Requerido</option>
          </select>
          <button onClick={e => this.addItem(e)}>Añade otro</button>
        </form>
        <div>
          <h4>Mis Tiempos:</h4>
          <ul>{get_times}</ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Todo />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya vi el problema, es que al agregar item no estaba limpiando los states de data_object por lo que esto queda asi:

```
addItem = e => {
 e.preventDefault();
 let obj = this.state.data_object;
 this.setState({
   times: this.state.times.concat(obj),
   data_object: {
     item: '',
     select: ''
   };
 });
};
```